# Finding the Rank of a player from the scoreboard

Tags: mysql

```
ID username score

4 |  x     | 7
7 |  y     | 3
9 |  z     | 6
```

I want to learn y's place at the scoreboard (which is 3.) from MySQL. I could not find the true MySQL query, can you help me?

Comment: what do you mean by place of a player?

Comment: I mean, which rank it is. x is the first, z is the second, y is the third as you see if we group them by score.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank, id,username, score
FROM table , (SELECT @rank := 0) r
ORDER BY score
) k
WHERE k.username = 'y'
```

Comment: hello, are you sure about your syntax is true? because, it gives error when try this.

Comment: Now, this; http://666kb.com/i/c69cq4sacducpwjhd.gif

My table; http://666kb.com/i/c69cqfmlhrdht4881.png

Comment: miss out comma in between nickname and money.

Comment: It worked! But with a little mistake, it shows the first place user as last place user :) I added DESC and that's it! Thanks :)